# Within an ng-repeat, how can I pass the value of a element to a directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an event object whose data comes from a json, this event has an array of videos which I am trying to display as YouTube embeds. I am trying to use a directive to accomplish this but it is not working within the ng-repeat I am doing for the videos. This is the code of the directive:

```
app.directive('youtube', function($sce) {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: { code:'=' },
    replace: true,
    template: '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="{{url}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>',
    link: function (scope) {
        scope.$watch('code', function (newVal) {
           if (newVal) {
               scope.url = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + newVal);
           }
        });
    }
  };
});
```

When I try to use it like this, then it doesn't works, the variable is not parsed if I use the curly brackets and it doesn't works either without them:

```
<div ng-repeat="video in event.videos" class="embed">
   <div youtube code="{{video}}"></div>
</div>
```

The {{video}} element has the id of the YouTube video, if I do this ng-repeat without the directive, the video ids print fine, so it is working but not parsing it when used within the directive.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the watch get fired with correct code value.

Comment: It wasn't being fired correctly; yet I am wondering if the scope.$watch is even necessary in the first place. EliteOctagon's answer solved the issue for me.

Comment: I think you do need to watch it, but only for changes. If you don't expect the value to change, then you don't need to watch it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try ng-src in your template

`app.directive('youtube', function($sce) {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: { code:'=' },
    replace: true,
    template: '',
    link: function (scope) {
        scope.$watch('code', function (newVal, oldVal) { // use newVal and oldVal
           console.log(newVal); // log it to see that it is passed
           if (newVal !== undefined) {
               scope.url = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + newVal);
           }
        });
    }
  };
});`

also, in your HTML, you don't need {{ }} around video, its already a variable on the scope

```
<div ng-repeat="video in event.videos" class="embed">
   <div youtube code="video"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yep, that did the trick! It is working fine now. Thanks. Not quite clear on the newVal and oldVal part tho, is the scope.$watch expecting a variable that is declared within the controler, even tho it comes from the query to the json object? Looks like that part of the code could be removed altogether?

Comment: the newVal/oldVal is just very standard syntax. $watch can accept any variable as long as it's in your directive. Using = means your scope.code is two way data bound, meaning you can send changes to it back to the controller. If your scope.code value isn't going to change, no need to watch it.